# How to set EditText value it depend on AutoCompleteTextView value in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, autocompletetextview

There are one AutoCompleteTextView, Edittext and Button in dialog box. If AutoCompleteTextView is used Focus on dropdown. so it can easily select. If anyone select **AAA** in autocompletetextview then set edittext value to **BBB**. eg. If select **CCC** then set editext value to **DDD**. EditText value will be change by the value of AutoCompleteTextView selection. How can i set if AutoComplete was **AAA** then set value to Edittext **BBB**.

Pls see my code below:

```
    private EditText editText;

    private AutoCompleteTextView completeTextView;

    String[] items = { "AAA","CCC","EEE", "GGG"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //AuutoCompleteTextView 
        completeTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.complete_text);

        // show list on focus
        completeTextView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                completeTextView.showDropDown();                
                return false;
            }

        });

        completeTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    if (completeTextView.toString().equals("AAA")) {                        
                        editText.setText("BBB",TextView.BufferType.NORMAL);
                        }

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });




        completeTextView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, items));


        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);     


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code:

```
private EditText editText;

private AutoCompleteTextView completeTextView;

String[] items = { "AAA","CCC","EEE", "GGG"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //AuutoCompleteTextView 
    completeTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.complete_text);

    completeTextView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, items));


    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);     

    completeTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        if(items[position].equals("AAA"){
           editText.setText("BBB");}
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
actv.setOnSelectedListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //... your stuff
    }
})
```

References:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html